# Regex closing tag replacement issue

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

We have a piece of regex that adds a `<strong>` tag around keywords if they are not within a certain closing tag themselves. This has always worked nicely...

```
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $str = preg_replace("/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+(<\/strong>|<\/a>|<\/b>|<\/i>|<\/u>|<\/em>)))\b(" . preg_quote($keyword, "/") . ")\b/is", "<strong>\\2</strong>", $str, 1);
}
```

So if the keyword was `test` this would change:

```
A test line
```

to:

```
A <strong>test</strong> line
```

but this would not change:

```
<a href="">A test line</a>
```

As you can see the list of closing tags we want it to ignore is in the regex.

We have encountered a problem with a string that looks like:

```
<a href="">A test <em>line</em></a>
```

It's not recognising the closing `</a>` or `</em>` for that matter, so it's coming out as...

```
<a href="">A <strong>test</strong> <em>line</em></a>
```

Which we don't want it to do. Can anyone see if there is a fix to this (and yes I am aware of the don't parse HTML with regex rule so posting links to that infamous post is not an answer ;-))

Comment: Sorry, but... If you are aware of it, why are you STILL parsing HTML with Regex? ;-)

Comment: I'm aware that you're aware of the don't parse HTML with regex rule so I will post the link to the infamous post anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex try to match the keyword `test` not enclosed by either `a,b,i,u,em,strong` tags.

**Regex**

```
/^.*?(?!<(a|b|i|u|em|strong).*?>.*?)\btest\b(?!.*?<\/\1>)/i
```

**Test**

```
A test line                          => MATCH
<a href="">A test line</a>           => NO MATCH
<a href="">A test <em>line</em></a>  => NO MATCH
```

**Discussion**

```
^.*?(?!<(a|b|i|u|em|strong).*?>.*?)   => The keyword `test' must not be preceded by 
                                         any tag listed followed by any character
\btest\b                              => Here we define the keyword we want to match
(?!.*?</\1>)                          => The keyword `test' must not be followed by
                                         the tag opened previously
```

**Tip**

You can enhance the regexp for multiple keywords (kw1,kw2,kw3 in the example below) like this :

```
/^.*?(?!<(a|b|i|u|em|strong).*?>.*?)\b(?:kw1|kw2|kw3)\b(?!.*?<\/\1>)/i
```

**Warning**

This regex actually works on the provided test but not in all cases.

Comment: `$str = preg_replace('/(?<!<(a|b|i|u|em|strong).*?>.*?)\btest\b(?!.*?</\1>)/i', "<strong>\\2</strong>", "A test line", 1);`

Gives error: Unknown modifier '\'

Comment: I have changed the regexp according to php regex flavor limitation.

Comment: I must admit regex is not well suited in this case. Anyway, those kind of challenge are always fun.

Comment: Indeed.. now the issue is that you dont' see the text before the matching word... `$str = preg_replace("/^.*?(?!<(a|b|i|u|em|strong).*?>.*?)\b(test)\b(?!.*?<\/\1>)/is", "<strong>\\2</strong>", "A test line", 1);`

Comment: Try this : `$str = preg_replace("/^(.*?)(?!<(a|b|i|u|em|strong).*?>.*?)\b(test)\b(?!.*?<\/\2>)/is", "\\1<strong>\\3</strong>", "A test line", 1);`